# How can partial derivatives of a function be expressed as components of a covector field independently of coordinates?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

At the end of page 280 of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifold* the author states

> Although the partial derivatives of a smooth function cannot be interpreted in a
> coordinate-independent way as the components of a vector field, it turns out that they *can* be interpreted as the components of a covector field. This is the most important
> application of covector fields.

What does the above passage mean? It would help if someone could rephrase what the author means more rigorously.

---

In the next passages, the author shows that, *given smooth coordinates $(x^i)$*, we may write
$$\text{d}f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\text{d}x^i.$$

Is *this* what the author meant in the quoted passage? If so, in what sense is the above equality 'coordinate-independent'?

Comment: Do you know what are $dx^i$'s? And $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$?

Answer (score 2):

Given a coordinate chart, $(U,x)$, I hope you know that there is the corresponding chart-induced vector fields on $U$, namely $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1},\dots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\right\}$. For each $p\in U$, these vector fields evaluated at $p$ give a basis for $T_pM$. Next, for any covector field $\omega$ on $U$, it has components relative to the above basis simply by evaluating the covector field on each of the basis vector fields, namely $\omega_{(x),i}:=\omega\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)$ (perform a pointwise evaluation on $U$; this gives us a function $\omega_{(x),i}:U\to\Bbb{R}$). From these components, we can recover the full covector field simply as $\omega=\omega_{(x),i}\,dx^i$. If this last step is not clear then you should revisit the situation in a single vector space $V$. Take a basis $\{e_1,\dots, e_n\}$ for $V$, construct the dual basis $\{\epsilon^1,\dots, \epsilon^n\}$, and prove that for each $v\in V$, we have $v=\sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon^i(v)e_i$ and for each $\lambda\in V^*$, we have $\lambda=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda(e_i)\epsilon^i$; the $\epsilon^i(v)$ and $\lambda(e_i)$ are typically just written $v^i,\lambda_i$ respectively.

Now, you can play this game with $\omega=df$. By unwinding some definitions, you will see that the component $(df)_{(x),i}$ is exactly the $i^{th}$ coordinate partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$, and by applying the above linear algebra fact, we get out beloved $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\,dx^i$.

Regarding coordinate-independence, it simply means that the defintion of $df$ doesn’t depend on coordinates. Using coordinates, it can be built out of things which do depend on coordinates (namely $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ and $dx^i$ separately) but their specific linear combination is $df$ and that doesn’t depend on coordinates.